# Blender crashing when texture painting in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Currently using Blender 2.78 I'm attempting to texture an image created within Blender that is being mix with another image texture using the mix RGB node which is routed into the shader it won't let me paint on the image despite having the paint slot selected once I have my nodes set up and try to save the file Blender just closes[image: cycles nodes]

Comment: Did you unwrap the model?

Comment: Yup, it is definitely UVed. I figured out how get the texture painting working I had a black texture alpha mask loaded somehow, but saving is still causing it to crash on me. I create a new scene from scratch and set a simple cube to paint on in cycles with the same node set up and worked fine and I can save it. The file that is giving me issues is from someone else it may be from an older version of Blender. I've simply switched back to Blender Render for now.

Comment: thats a similar problem http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70521/when-i-try-to-texture-paint-my-model-my-computer-freezes-solved